# Dropwizard logging appender error

Tags: dropwizard

I have a dropwizard service which has been running for months with logging to console. I wanted to now log to file so I added the following extra lines to my config file:

```
    logging:

  # Permit DEBUG, INFO, WARN and ERROR messages to be logged by appenders.
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: ./log/taskiir-service.log
      threshold: ALL
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./log/taskiir-service-%d.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
```

However when I try to run the service now I get the following error:

```
    io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: taskiir-service.yml has an error:
  * Failed to parse configuration at: logging.appenders.[0]; Could not resolve type id 'file' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory<ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent>]: known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'appenders')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.anton.taskiirservice.TaskiirService.TaskiirAPIConfiguration["logging"]->io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory["appenders"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])

    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:276)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:157)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:92)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:124)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:72)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.anton.taskiirservice.TaskiirService.TaskiirAPIApplication.main(TaskiirAPIApplication.java:59)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'file' as a subtype of [simple type, class io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory<ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent>]: known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'appenders')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.anton.taskiirservice.TaskiirService.TaskiirAPIConfiguration["logging"]->io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory["appenders"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.invalidTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1615)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1186)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._handleUnknownTypeId(TypeDeserializerBase.java:291)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:162)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:113)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:254)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:519)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SettableObjectMethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableObjectMethodProperty.java:47)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:287)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:189)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:120)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedUsingDefaultImpl(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:178)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:105)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:254)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:251)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.afterburner.deser.SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.deserialize(SuperSonicBeanDeserializer.java:155)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3972)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2264)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.BaseConfigurationFactory.build(BaseConfigurationFactory.java:128)
    ... 6 more
```

Any ideas most welcome, thanks.

Here is the POM file (using Eclipse):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <groupId>com.anton.taskiirservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>TaskiirService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TaskiirAPI</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <dropwizard.version>1.2.2</dropwizard.version>
        <mainClass>com.anton.taskiirservice.TaskiirService.TaskiirAPIApplication</mainClass>
        <swagger.version>1.5.3-M1</swagger.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
            <artifactId>dropwizard-jdbi</artifactId>
            <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.7</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
                    <!-- exclude signed Manifests -->
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                    <dependencyDetailsEnabled>false</dependencyDetailsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you making a fat jar? Can you add your pom.xml? Since its saying 'known type ids = []', it implies the service files may not be present.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have added the POM file that I am using in Eclipse.  I am making a runnable JAR file where I extract the libraries into the JAR

Comment: Being that you're using the maven shade plugin check out the file META-INF/services/io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory in your service jar file.  It's possibly missing the required configs for this to work such as: ServicesResourcesTransformer or the FileAppenderFactory.  Source: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/810